# Hide/disable EDIT & DELETE links in menu-customize form

Tags: 6, routes, navigation

How to hide/disable EDIT & DELETE links in menu-customize form.

www.yoursite.com/admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links

I think that those links bring more potential problems than benefits. It would be great if anyone knew how to disable them per role but a global disable is fine too. I'm using Drupal 6.

p.s. I still want user to have permission to rearrange menu items ordering.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could hide these links using css formatting.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Currently they do not have any class/id i can grab on to. Maybe if i override function that generate output i'll be able to add extra classes. Do you have hint how to do that?

Comment: Do you want them disabled for all menus or just primary links?

Comment: Just primary-links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a small custom module and implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6).  Below is a quick example for Drupal 6:

**.module file**

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_menu_overview_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  GLOBAL $user;

  // Check if user has a certain role or not and menu is primary links
  // Change ROLEID to the role id you want operations hidden from
  if (!array_key_exists(ROLEID, $user->roles) && arg(3) == 'primary-links') {

    // Hide edit/delete menu operations
    foreach ($form as $key => $ele) {
      if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'mlid:') {
        unset($form[$key]['operations']);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Change `YOURMODULE` to the name of the module you are creating.  For assistance creating custom modules, see the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

To work in Drupal 7, I *believe* all you would need to do is change `arg(3)` to `arg(4)` due to the path changes.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks!

It, seams that third argument "$form_id" should be left out.

Comment: Also, it seams that in condition "!" is not needed.

Comment: Ah good catche, changed from hook_form_alter to hook_form_FORM_ID_alter, forgot to remove the `$form_id`. The "!" I used in testing on my own site. It just depends if you want to check if a user has a role or doesn't have a role. If only giving permission to see these links to one or two roles, would be easier to use `!` instead of repeating `array_key_exists()` for each role you want them hidden from

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `$key => $ele` and then the `$form[$key]` was a savior. I was trying to directly alter `$ele` without any luck.